# Unable to update state value in react native

Tags: react-native

```
    const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);
    const [progress, setProgress]   = useState(1);

    const onProgress  =  (progress) => {
        console.log(progress)
        setProgress(progress)
    }

        <View style={styles.countdown}>
            <CountDown isPaused={!isStarted} onProgress={onProgress} />
        </View>




    const minutesToMillis = (min) =>  min * 1000 * 60;
    const formatTime = (time) => time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;

    export const CountDown = ({minutes=20, isPaused, onProgress}) => {
        const interval = React.useRef(null);
        
        const countDown = () => {
            setMillis((time) => {
                if(time === 0){
                    return time;
                } 
                const timeLeft = time - 1000;

                onProgress(timeLeft / minutesToMillis(minutes))

                return timeLeft;
            })
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            if(isPaused){
                return
            }
            interval.current = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
            return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
        }, [isPaused])

        const [millis, setMillis] = useState(minutesToMillis(minutes));
        const minute = Math.floor(millis / 1000 / 60) % 60;
        const seconds = Math.floor(millis / 1000 ) % 60;

        return (
            <Text style={styles.text}>
                {formatTime(minute)}:{formatTime(seconds)}
            </Text>
        )
    }
```

error:

```
    react native cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component
```

Here i am just trying to update state but, getting above error while updating.
Please take a look

I have shared countDown component also.

Please take a look

Here i am just trying to update state but, getting above error while updating.
Please take a look

I have shared countDown component also.

Comment: Can you share the component the above code is being called in?

Comment: updated. added in question

Comment: thanks. can you share CountDown component as well?

Answer (score 1):

You were passing the `isPaused` as `true` because that interval was not getting triggered and that is the reason your timer state was not getting updated.

**Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/unable-to-update-state-value-in-react-native)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);

  const onProgress = (progress) => {
    console.log(progress);
    setProgress(progress);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CountDown isPaused={isStarted} onProgress={onProgress} />
      <Button title={!isStarted?"PAUSE":"RESTART"} onPress={() => setIsStarted(!isStarted)} />
    </View>
  );
}

const minutesToMillis = (min) => min * 1000 * 60;
const formatTime = (time) => (time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time);

const CountDown = ({ minutes = 20, isPaused, onProgress }) => {
  const interval = React.useRef(null);
  const [millis, setMillis] = useState(minutesToMillis(minutes));
  const minute = Math.floor(millis / 1000 / 60) % 60;
  const seconds = Math.floor(millis / 1000) % 60;

  const countDown = () => {
    console.log('hi');
    setMillis((time) => {
      if (time === 0) {
        return time;
      }
      const timeLeft = time - 1000;

      onProgress(timeLeft / minutesToMillis(minutes));

      return timeLeft;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPaused) {
      return;
    }
    interval.current = setInterval(() => countDown(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
  }, [isPaused]);

  return (
    <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
      {formatTime(minute)}:{formatTime(seconds)}
    </Text>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an error while calling onProgress.

```
<View style={styles.countdown}>
     <CountDown isPaused={!isStarted} onProgress={()=>this.onProgress(progress)} />
</View>
```

I never worked with react native but both seems similar enough. So, I think the above solution works for you.

Comment: @KiranSyoutubechannel is there any error with this code.

Comment: export const CountDown = ({minutes=20, isPaused, onProgress, progress}) try to do this and then access it or do one thing inside your component define these methods and state.